# ServiceStack auth with multiple repositories

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, servicestack

There are multiple AuthProviders we can setup for servicestack. But all of them supposed to use one user repository. Is there a way to setup, let's say, one basic auth provider and two different repositories for different routes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No to multiple repositories out of the box:

The short answer is you can't simply use multiple repositories out of the box. The reason it doesn't support this is because the `CredentialsProvider` uses the AppHost dependancies container *(IoC)* to resolve the `IUserAuthRepository`, so it only expects one repository, *besides it would need more information about which repository to use from your routes*.

You could write your own `CredentialsProvider`, and then write a new `BasicAuthProvider` that extends from it, but this is a lot of work for simple basic auth. And if you were using the `InMemoryAuthRepository` or `RedisAuthRepository` you would find that even though you made separate instances the repositories will in fact be merged because they use the same cache key. :(

```
// This doesn't work. The repositories will merge.

var repository1 = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
repository1.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth { Id = 1, UserName = "cburns", FullName = "Charles Montgomery Burns" }, "excellent");
repository1.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth { Id = 2, UserName = "bartsimpson", FullName = "Bart Simpson" }, "Ay caramba");
repository1.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth { Id = 3, UserName = "homersimpson", FullName = "Homer J. Simpson" }, "donuts");

var repository2 = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
repository2.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth { Id = 1, UserName = "thehulk", FullName = "The Hulk" }, "pebbles");
repository2.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth { Id = 2, UserName = "captainamerican", FullName = "Captain America" }, "redwhiteblue");
repository2.CreateUserAuth(new UserAuth { Id = 3, UserName = "spiderman", FullName = "Spider Man" }, "withgreatpower");
```

### Implement your own authentication:

ServiceStack has great extendibility, and you can easily role your own authentication. Basic Auth is a very simple protocol.

I simply created this `RequestFilterAttribute` that allows you to use any number of custom repository.

**[Full Source Code Here](https://gist.github.com/scottmcarthur/8577465)** *ServiceStack v4 Self Hosted Application*

**Simple Custom Repository.** *You could use a more complex repository, and include database lookups etc. But this simple for demonstration purposes:*

```
public class MyUserRepository
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Users { get; set; }

    public MyUserRepository(string name, Dictionary<string, string> users = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        Users = users ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

**The `RequestFilterAttribute`.** *i.e. does the authentication*

```
public class BasicAuthAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute {

    readonly string _realmName;
    readonly string _repositoryName;

    public BasicAuthAttribute(string realmName, string repositoryName = null)
    {
        _realmName = realmName;
        _repositoryName = repositoryName ?? realmName;
    }

    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        // Get the correct repository to authenticate against
        var repositories = HostContext.TryResolve<MyUserRepository[]>();
        MyUserRepository repository = null;
        if(repositories != null)
            repository = repositories.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == _repositoryName);

        // Determine if request has basic authentication
        var authorization = req.GetHeader(HttpHeaders.Authorization);

        if(repository != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization) && authorization.StartsWith("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // Decode the credentials
            var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authorization.Substring(6))).Split(':');
            if(credentials.Length == 2)
            {
                // Try and match the credentials to a user
                var password = repository.Users.GetValueOrDefault(credentials[0]);
                if(password != null && password == credentials[1])
                {
                    // Credentials are valid
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        // User requires to authenticate
        res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        res.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.WwwAuthenticate, string.Format("basic realm=\"{0}\"", _realmName));
        res.EndRequest();
    }
}
```

**Usage:** It's usage is simple. Decorate your action method or DTO with the attribute:

```
public static class TestApp
{

    [Route("/TheSimpsons", "GET")]
    public class TheSimpsonsRequest {}

    [Route("/Superheros", "GET")]
    public class SuperherosRequest {}

    public class TestController : Service
    {
        [BasicAuth("The Simpsons", "Simpsons")] // Requires a 'Simpsons' user
        public object Get(TheSimpsonsRequest request)
        {
            return new { Town = "Springfield", Mayor = "Quimby" };
        }

        [BasicAuth("Superheros")] // Requires a user from 'Superheros'
        public object Get(SuperherosRequest request)
        {
            return new { Publishers = new[] { "Marvel", "DC" } };
        }
    }
}
```

**[BasicAuth(***string* **realmName,** *string* **repositoryName)]**

- `realmName` is the name to display in the authentication dialog
- `repositoryName` is the name of repository to look in for credentials. It is optional, if excluded it will use the `realmName` as the repository name.

**Setup** The demo configures the repository statically in the `AppHost` `Configure` method:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    container.Register<MyUserRepository[]>(c => new[] 
    { 
        new MyUserRepository("Simpsons", new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "cburns", "excellent" },
            { "bartsimpson", "Ay caramba" },
            { "homersimpson", "donuts" }
        }), 
        new MyUserRepository("Superheros", new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "thehulk", "pebbles" },
            { "captainamerica", "redwhiteblue" },
            { "spiderman", "withgreatpower" }
        })
    });
}
```

**Testing:** When you navigate to `/TheSimpsons` the service will prompt for a 'Simpsons' credential, it won't allow a 'Superheros' credential here. And when you go to `/Superheros` the reverse is true.

---

I appreciate that this solution does deviate from the ServiceStack authentication provider. As mentioned it is possible to build your own authentication from the ground up using the ServiceStack authentication providers, but it will be difficult, and beyond the scope of StackOverflow. If you want to do this, you can read through the existing providers and determine how this is done. However my advise is, if you don't need that complexity, then work from the above example.

Comment: That was a brilliant advice, dear sir.